# Why is Orchard.AntiSpam reCaptcha displayed incorrectly?

Tags: orchardcms, recaptcha

Using Orchard 1.8.1 and Orchard AntiSpam Module for Google reCaptcha it all works but I get a deformed display:

Sorry, can't show image because stackoverflow won't let me. So apologies for the following word picture. The table tag seems to fall apart. `Stop spam` and `read books` are gone and there are two red lines under the widget. Also, the vertical stack of buttons (refresh, audio and help) is malformed and extends down past the bottom of the widget.

It is the same on Google Chrome and IE. Have not tried other browsers.

I looked at Google's Developer site for reCaptcha but it was very little help. I've been over the generated HTML and it seems reasonable; at least I cannot see any obvious errors, and I've experimented with various solutions listed on stackoverflow without success.

Anyone have any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: Try inspecting the CSS rules on the page in the browser

Comment: Did you check the browser console for js errors? Also you can try the Designer Tools (Orchard module) to inspect the template that is being used.